# Cannot lock to custom z-axis when extrude-scaling with custom orientation

Tags: edit-mode

I have a part of a mesh selected, using a custom orientation called "ventil".

[image: part of mesh selected]

Now, if I want to add some thickness to the cylinder, by extrusion scaling it with

<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

I will be able to lock out the Z axis of the *normal* orientation in the extrusion, but not the *custom orientation* "ventil", which I actually expected would be the orientation to use.

Why?

Extrusions seems to only use "Normal", but grabbing uses the custom orientation.

Is this a bug?

(I would create the tag "Orientations" to this question if I had 300 reputation)

Comment: I have already assumes this must be a bug and reported it in https://developer.blender.org/T52558

Comment: In the docs it suggests the (somewhat cumbersome) workflow of cancelling the default extrusion movement and then resuming as an ordinary transform, which is then able to use the custom orientation.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#workflow